# Get height of text in PDF AcroField

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is there any technique to calculate the height of text in AcroField?

In other words, I have a template PDF with a body section that I want to paste my long text into and I want to get the height of the text. If it overflows, insert a new page for rest of the text.

Answer (score 1):

This will give height and width:

```
Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
Vector topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
    curBaseline[Vector.I1], curBaseline[Vector.I2], 
    topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]
);
Single curFontSize = rect.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your field to a font size of zero.  This will automatically size the font so that the given text will fit into your field... within certain limits.  I don't think it'll shrink below 6 points.

Another alternative would be to use a `ColumnText` and call `myColText.go(true)`.  This will "simulate" layout, letting you know what goes where without actually drawing anything to the PDF.  Just whip up a columnText with the same dimensions, font&font-size as your field, and your results should be the same.

In fact, I believe iText's text field rendering code uses `ColumnText` internally.  Yep, have a look at the source for `TextField.getAppearance()`.

Note that the bounding box of your field isn't going to match the box the text is laid out into... you have to account for borer style & thickness.  That's why I suggest you look at the source.